# Replace xml attribute values with constant values by xsl

Tags: xslt, xpath, svg, xslt-1.0

there is that XML Node

```
<svg>
    <g transform="translate(113.63-359.13)">
        <use fill="#f00" xlink:href="#D"/>
        <g transform="translate(72.59-8.504)">
            <use xlink:href="#E"/>
            <path fill="#f00" stroke="#000" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".24" d="m6.04 526.26h19.843v4.961h-19.843z"/>
            <use xlink:href="#F"/>
        </g>
        <text x="20.41" y="527.6" fill="#000" font-family="Arial" font-size="8">ProcessOutbound</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

which can be found by this Xpath

```
/svg/g[text="ProcessOutbound"]/use
```

also this work fine

```
/svg/g[text="ProcessOutbound"]/use/@fill
```

but for some reasons that xsl is not replaceing #f00 with #00f which is what have tired

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:param name="blue" select="'#00f'"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match='/svg/g[text="ProcessOutbound"]/use'>
        <xsl:attribute name='fill'>
            <xsl:value-of select="'$blue'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

actually the whole svg file is copied but the fill attribute is not replaced. I tried to achive a copy but with the replaced fill value

What is the correct way to replace attribut values with constant values by xsl ?

So the expected result should look like

```
   <g transform="translate(113.63-359.13)">
    <use fill="#00f" xlink:href="#D"/>
    <g transform="translate(72.59-8.504)">
        <use xlink:href="#E"/>
        <path fill="#f00" stroke="#000" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".24" d="m6.04 526.26h19.843v4.961h-19.843z"/>
        <use xlink:href="#F"/>
    </g>
    <text x="20.41" y="527.6" fill="#000" font-family="Arial" font-size="8">ProcessOutbound</text>
</g>
```

Comment: Your XML isn't valid. Please try posting the complete XML. And, in the fragment of XML you've shown, there are no matches I could find for `/svg/g[text="ProcessOutbound"]/use`

Comment: Show u r required text completely. And <SVG> is root element? if yes, alter that. I observed, some attributes in XML file are having braces '(', I assume that braces are not allowed within attributes.

Comment: it's difficult to post here the complete file as it is a bit big. The complete xpath would be /svg/g[8]/use/@fill

Comment: I am not asking entire XML, what may be the expected result for u r given input.

Comment: edited the posting in that way now. It's just the value of fill

Comment: @user3732793, <use fill="#00f" xlink:href="#D"/> is the result from my XSLT, check once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things incorrect with your XSLT:

- It is trying to replace the whole 'use' element with an attribute.
- You are using two pairs of quotes around `$blue`, which causes it to be treated as a string.
- You are not using namespaces even though your XML uses a namespace.

Please try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:param name="blue" select="'#00f'"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match='svg:g[svg:text = "ProcessOutbound"]/svg:use/@fill'>
        <xsl:attribute name='fill'>
            <xsl:value-of select="$blue"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="...">
    <g transform="translate(113.63-359.13)">
        <use xlink:href="#D" fill="#00f" />
        <g transform="translate(72.59-8.504)">
            <use xlink:href="#E" xmlns:xlink="x" />
            <path fill="#f00" d="m6.04 526.26h19.843v4.961h-19.843z" stroke-width=".24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke="#000" />
            <use xlink:href="#F" />
        </g>
        <text font-family="Arial" fill="#000" font-size="8" y="527.6" x="20.41">ProcessOutbound</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/d8pdoi

Comment: thanks for the addiotional Link . Even your Xpath selection works fine for the Attribute. Unfortunatetly the output for the whole file is still giving back the wrong result fill='#f00'. I'll see what the issue is thanks

Comment: @user3732793 As Michael Hor says, I suspect there is a namespace in your XML that you haven't shown us. I've modified my XSLT to use the standard svg` namespace. Could you give the updated version a try?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a well-formed input (the prefix `xlink:` is not bound because you did not include its namespace definition), use the stylesheet below.

Rather than matching the element `use`, directly match the node you'd like to modify, the `fill` attribute of `use`.

**Stylesheet**

Your question suggests that the second template should actually match `/svg/g[8]/use/@fill` if I understood correctly.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="blue" select="'#00f'"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/svg/g/use/@fill">
        <xsl:attribute name="fill">
            <xsl:value-of select="$blue"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <g transform="translate(113.63-359.13)">
      <use fill="#00f" xlink:href="#D"/>
      <g transform="translate(72.59-8.504)">
         <use xlink:href="#E"/>
         <path fill="#f00" stroke="#000" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".24" d="m6.04 526.26h19.843v4.961h-19.843z"/>
         <use xlink:href="#F"/>
      </g>
      <text x="20.41" y="527.6" fill="#000" font-family="Arial" font-size="8">ProcessOutbound</text>
   </g>
</svg>
```

**EDIT**: As mentioned in a comment, try the following stylesheet if your SVG elements actually are in a namespace:

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="blue" select="'#00f'"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/svg:svg/svg:g/svg:use/@fill">
        <xsl:attribute name="fill">
            <xsl:value-of select="$blue"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I wish It would work the same way for me....tried with XMLSpy how did you run it ?

Comment: @user3732793 See http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2C4/1. What XSLT processor are you using? The code above definitely produces the correct output, but of course we don't know how you embed this new piece into your existing stylesheet and what your actual input looks like. For instance, did you forget to mention that the SVG elements are in a namespace?

Comment: I have used XMLSpy. interesting what urls go around. see here I have added the complete svg http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2C4/2

Comment: @user3732793 I was asking about the XSLT processor, not about the IDE. Anyway, I have no idea what you mean by "interesting what urls go around". Would you mind explaining that? Now you have added the actual input file - and the elements really are in the SVG namespace. The current code you're linking to fails to match the `fill`attribute. Look for elements in this namespace: http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2C4/3.

Comment: Yes that is now also what I have search for thanks ! with the Urls I meant what you and others here use to show the xsl work

Comment: @user3732793 Please stop switching the accepted answer - all answers are equally correct and point out where you went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If I am guessing correctly and your input is a valid SVG document, then all its elements are in the **SVG namespace**. IOW, your **input example** should actually look like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g transform="translate(113.63-359.13)">
        <use fill="#f00" xlink:href="#D"/>
        <g transform="translate(72.59-8.504)">
            <use xlink:href="#E"/>
            <path fill="#f00" stroke="#000" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".24" d="m6.04 526.26h19.843v4.961h-19.843z"/>
            <use xlink:href="#F"/>
        </g>
        <text x="20.41" y="527.6" fill="#000" font-family="Arial" font-size="8">ProcessOutbound</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

And then your **XSLT**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="blue" select="'#00f'"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="svg:g[svg:text='ProcessOutbound']/svg:use/@fill">
    <xsl:attribute name='fill'>
        <xsl:value-of select="$blue"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @user3732793 So why isn't this the accepted answer?

Comment: Yes, that's the correct answer - but so is JLRishe's and mine. But I don't mind whose answer is accepted.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I don't mind either. I thought it would be helpful to have the correct answer at the top, though. As for the other answers being correct ... ah, I see they are *now*. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:param name="blue" select="'#00f'"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/svg/g[contains(text, 'ProcessOutbound')]/use">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:attribute name='fill'>
        <xsl:value-of select="$blue"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If this not meeting u r requirement, provide u r simple required text.

Comment: sorry no that doesn't work. I still have f00 not 00f as vaule in the output